# Am I creating a CSP issue for myself?

Tags: node.js, express, http, security, content-security-policy

I've set up my node.js/express project to use `<img>`'s that are stored in S3. I get this error message when referencing them: `.....because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".`

So I use this code below to change the CSP, since none of the `<meta>` tags I found on here solved my error. I just want to make sure this isn't creating a security issue, since I know very little about CSP

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'")

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSP it totally insecure because it restricts nothing.

**Scripts**
`script-src http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` allows external scripts from any sources, allows inline scripts and eval-functions.

Instead `http://*` of you should to specify whitelist of allowed sources for scripts loading, for example:

```
script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com tagmanager.google.com ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ googletagmanager.com https://connect.facebook.net;
```

`'unsafe-eval'` is required only if some scripts use *eval()* / *Function()* / *setInterval()* / *setTimeout()* functions.

Try to avoid `'unsafe-inline'` by use 'nonce-value' token.

`*` The same is applied for `style-src`.

**images**
If you load images from Amazon S3, you can specify a domain name of your bucket in the `img-src`, like `img-src 'self' https://bucketname.s3.Region.amazonaws.com`.
You can fully open all sources for images `img-src *`, but for images ONLY, not for scripts, styles, iframes etc.
`data:` in `img-src` required only if you use data:-URLs like `<img src='data:image/gif;base64,...'>` or CSS constricts like `background-url(data:image/jpeg;base64,...)`.

**default-src**
Good practice is `default-src 'self';` - all unspecified fallback directives limited to self domain.

CSP must be as restrictive as possible to ensure safety.